# Start executing an exe file in windows, restart computer, and pick up where the process left off

Tags: c#, .net

Is this at all possible? If so, how? The flow would be something like:

```
private void DoStuff() 
{
   // Do some stuff
   RestartPc();
}

private void RestartPc()
{
   Process.Start("shutdown", "/r /t 0"); 
}

// Call this when the PC is restarted:
private void DoStuffAfterRestart() {}
```

All this code would be a **windows service**, so what would be the 'best' way to tell the `OnStart` method to skip `DoStuff` **if** pc was restarted and go straight to `DoStuffAfterRestart` since service would be set to auto start.

Comment: Where exactly is the issue ? you could write your last executed step to a database, json file,.... and then determine what to do next after restart. or do you have issues with the restert itself ?

Comment: actually your process has stages, once your process finish one of the stages, store it in an xml file and when then window start again read this xml and continue from that stage

Comment: It's unavoidably a pretty generic comment because answer may be long but: did you consider to use **Workflow Foundation**? If you're performing e sequence of activity then you may persist workflow state, restart computer and then resume workflow (from very next step). Also **Application Recovery and Restart** can be used for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idk if there are special methods for this but i would have a solution:

Add your program to the autostart. EDIT: Like @PTwr pointed out you shouldn't use the normal autostart. Use the [Run once registry key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Change the code to something like so:

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
    var x = loadState();
    if(x == null)
        DoStuff();
    else
        DoStuffAfterRestart();
}

private void DoStuff() 
{
   // Do some stuff
   SafeState();
   RestartPc();
}

// Call this when the PC is restarted:
private void DoStuffAfterRestart() {}
```

In the safe/load methods you would have to write something to a file/registry to remember your current state

By saving you 'current position' you can 'remember' where you have been the last time and do the right stuff after a restart.

Comment: yes, that's the best way to go in this situation. thanks ;)

Comment: @Mefhisto1 You are welcome. See my edit for more thoughts.

Comment: Do not use old "autostart", especially if you want to run it only once. Use [RunOnce registry key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.